# in vim, how to append/insert text with argdo?

Tags: vim, insert, append, vi

There's the ":a" command, but that's multi-line, and argdo asks you for the text again for each file.

The docs mention the global command (g/pat/command) that will use an alternative version of ":a" that is terminated by a newline instead of by "." on a line (you can include newlines by escaping them with "\").  But I couldn't get this to work.

The only way I've seen is to first yank the text-to-be-added into a named register, then use:

```
:argdo put x                 " where x is the register
```

I'm hoping for something like

```
:argdo append myTextHere
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm unclear where you're trying to insert the text in the buffer.  If you want it after the current line:

```
:argdo exe 'normal osometext'
```

Inserting text with linebreaks in it:

```
:argdo exe "normal osometext\<CR>anewline"
```

Comment: hey that's pretty cool.  I've seen "normal" before but not used it. BTW  I found this also worked:  :argdo normal osometext

Comment: I should have answered your request for clarity:  sometimes I'd want to insert it at the same line in each of the files (eg. line 2); sometimes after a certain pattern.  I probably wouldn't want to do it in terms of the current line, because it might be different in the different files.  But I think your approach is easily powerful enough to be adapted to this, by going to a line or searching for a pattern, before inserting.

Comment: This is beautiful, I LOVE THIS! For example :argdo exe 'normal zR' to unfold all tabs.

Answer (score 2):

To append text after line nr 10:

```
:argdo call append(10, "hello world")
```

To append text to the line 10:

```
:argdo call setline(10, getline(10)."textappended")
```

Comment: thanks, that seems workable. It's looking like one needs to switch to a different level to do this (using either your "call" or Brian's "normal")

Answer (score 1):

Yanking a text in vim will put it in the default buffer, which is `"`. You can paste that buffer in insert mode for example by typing `<C-R>"`. So all you need is `argdo put "`

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for something that didn't involve setting up registers.  Something like:  :argdo append myTextHere  I'll clarify the question.